# pattern searching in perl

Tags: perl

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

open(FILE1, "/cygdrive/c/cpros/mola.txt");
my $line = <FILE1>;
print $line;
close(FILE1);
open(FILE1, ">/cygdrive/c/cpros/mola.txt");

if ($line = ~ /karthik/)
{
  print FILE1 ("1");
}
else
{
  print FILE1 ("0");
}

close(FILE1);
```

I have stored hello world in mola.txt file but still its printing 1 but the pattern karthik is not saved in file but why its printing 1 ?
how to make search patterns?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`=~` is a separate operator, so it shouldn't have whitespace between its characters. With the whitespace, the condition of the `if` statement becomes an assignment that always yields true.

Comment: @cody: you are supposed to click the tick on the left.

Comment: @Blagovest That particular assignment always returns a true value, but all assignments do not return true values. For example: `print "Yes" if ($a = 0);` does not print "Yes".